# GCP cloud vpn to cisco FTD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cisco-vpn, google-cloud-vpn

I have a cloud VPN setup on GCP and I intend to connect to Cisco FTD. I have completed the setting on GCP end using a classic vpn route based policy.
The setup on the third party is also completed but I keep seeing "No incoming packets" on GCP end.
I checked the logs and I see that a communication hasnt even been established.

> 2023-12-08 08:02:54.217 creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1}
>
> 2023-12-08 08:02:54.217 initiating IKE_SA vpn_196.43.215.1[443] to
> 196.43.215.1 2023-12-08 08:02:54.222 generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG)
> N(REDIR_SUP) ] 2023-12-08 08:02:54.223 sending packet: from
> 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:02:55.223 retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08
> 08:02:55.223 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:02:56.223 retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08 08:02:56.223 sending packet: from
> 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:02:57.217 creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08
> 08:02:57.217 ignoring acquire for reqid 1, connection attempt pending
> 2023-12-08 08:02:57.223 retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
> 2023-12-08 08:02:57.224 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:02:58.224 retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08 08:02:58.224 sending packet: from
> 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:02:59.224 retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08
> 08:02:59.224 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:00.217 creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08 08:03:00.217 ignoring acquire
> for reqid 1, connection attempt pending 2023-12-08 08:03:00.224 giving
> up after 5 retransmits 2023-12-08 08:03:00.224 establishing IKE_SA
> failed, peer not responding 2023-12-08 08:03:03.217 creating acquire
> job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08 08:03:03.217 initiating
> IKE_SA vpn_196.43.215.1[444] to 196.43.215.1 2023-12-08 08:03:03.222
> generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP)
> N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ] 2023-12-08 08:03:03.223 sending
> packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes)
> 2023-12-08 08:03:04.223 retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
> 2023-12-08 08:03:04.223 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:05.224 retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08 08:03:05.224 sending packet: from
> 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:06.217 creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08
> 08:03:06.217 ignoring acquire for reqid 1, connection attempt pending
> 2023-12-08 08:03:06.224 retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
> 2023-12-08 08:03:06.224 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:07.224 retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08 08:03:07.224 sending packet: from
> 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:08.224 retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08
> 08:03:08.224 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:09.217 creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08 08:03:09.217 ignoring acquire
> for reqid 1, connection attempt pending 2023-12-08 08:03:09.225 giving
> up after 5 retransmits 2023-12-08 08:03:09.225 establishing IKE_SA
> failed, peer not responding 2023-12-08 08:03:12.217 creating acquire
> job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08 08:03:12.217 initiating
> IKE_SA vpn_196.43.215.1[445] to 196.43.215.1 2023-12-08 08:03:12.222
> generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP)
> N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ] 2023-12-08 08:03:12.223 sending
> packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes)
> 2023-12-08 08:03:13.224 retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
> 2023-12-08 08:03:13.224 sending packet: from 104.199.99.205[500] to
> 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:14.224 retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0 2023-12-08 08:03:14.224 sending packet: from
> 104.199.99.205[500] to 196.43.215.1[500] (892 bytes) 2023-12-08 08:03:15.217 creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} 2023-12-08
> 08:03:15.217 ignoring acquire for reqid 1, connection attempt pending

these are excerpts from the log